# Is there a continous function, for which $\int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx=0$ holds true $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, with $f(0)=1$?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

The question is heavily inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982998/is-there-a-continuous-function-satisfy-following-conditions?newreg=771eb1bb56f14c71a065b6db9b56e606), but generalizes the idea.

While thinking about it, I came up with $f(x)=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \cos(xy)$. Is this a (the only?) solution, and can this function even be considered continous?

Comment: I don't think that your $f$ can even be considered a function, because for $x\neq 0$ that limit does not exist.

Comment: The generalized idea is to have it hold true for $n=1,2,3,\ldots,N$ for some $N$. The answer is then yes and it's not hard to construct such a function, for example $f(x) = P_{N+1}(2x-1)(-1)^{N+1}$ with $P_k$ being the $k$th Legendre polynomial. There is no such function if you want it to hold for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The hypothesis implies that $\int x^{n} (xf(x))\, dx=0$ for $n=0,1,2,...$ and hence $\int p(x) (xf(x))\, dx=0$ for every polynomial $p$. Using Wierstrass Theorem conclude that $\int (xf(x))^{2}\, dx=0$ which gives $xf(x)=0$ for all $x$. Hence $f(0)=\lim f(\frac  1 n)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Stone Weierstrass says the polynomials are uniformly dense in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$.  Can you avail yourself of that fact to do the rest?